# Broadcasting uiimagePicker camera over airplay in landscape

Tags: uiimage, landscape, picker, airplay

I appreciate this is exotic but I have an app that uses an overlay for the uiimagePicker for directors and cinematographers. I understand that the uiimagePicker is only portrait and I have the overlay rotating fine to make the screen landscape. But I can't seem to find a way to tell this to airplay if the iphone is broadcasting it to the apple TV. Ideally the director can sit in front of the monitor while the dp previews the shot using the iphone but everyone currently has to lie on their side. Any ways around this?